# How can I curve an array of meshes without curving the mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a tank-track like-design, that I want to follow a curve.

But since the track-pieces themselves will not bend in real life, I don't want my render to bend.

No subdivision is applied, the edge-marks were just to test if that would work. It had no affect.

[image]

Comment: if it has no vertical edges it won't be able to bend, this is a solution

Comment: @moonboots It needs vertical edges for teeth and holes for the teeth.

Comment: so you can array a simple plane, enable its Instancing, and parent your rail object to the arrayed plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is duplication along a curve without deformation. Since 2.8 you can't use *Dupliframes* anymore, but you can do it this way:

Create a plane as long as your object, give it an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier so that it follows a curve:

[image]

Keep your plane selected, open the *Object* panel and under *Instancing*, enable *Faces*:

[image]

Parent your object to the plane, it won't deform even though it is subdivided:

[image]

Note: Maybe you'll need to set your curve to *Shape > Twist Method > Z-Up*

Comment: I found another answer elsewhere that helped a bit, and this cemented it, thank you! For anyone who might have an issue, make sure your objects rotation and scale are applied. Also, this may need you to change your array modifier's axis.

Comment: Is there a way to do this and discard the plane mesh data on export so you just get a single mesh of the non-deformed objects?

Comment: @Adam apply the modifiers of the plane, for the cuboid object press Ctrl A > Make Instances Real, the instances are still linked, to unlink select them all and go into the header menu > Object > Relations > Make SIngle User > Object & Data.

Comment: @moonboots Hey thanks, this is exactly what I wanted!