# Make this "Bicycle Chain" follow a curve perfectly, without warping

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

Yesterday I asked [How can I curve an array of meshes without curving the mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234409/how-can-i-curve-an-array-of-meshes-without-curving-the-mesh), and got a great answer from Moonboots.

My problem was how to make a mesh follow a curve without warping. They explained that I could parent to a plain of the same size.

[image]

Using that technique, I have a mesh that needs to overlap.

[image]

To do this, I need to use a relative offset of .915, or size the parent-plane to 91.5% of the width of the chain element. I've tried both.

*I'm not sure why blender is flipping my mesh, but it doesn't matter (unless it's what's causing this problem.) There are no rotations or inverse scales applied to any mesh or curve.*

I have a Curve, and an identically-shaped Bezier Curve, because I tried both, And no matter what I try, the links follow the curve poorly

[image]

The origins for the original chain link, parent-plane, and both curves are all in the same spot.

Comment: There are a couple of questions with working answers about how to make objects follow a curve in a snake like fashion.

Comment: @TheLabCat Thanks! I'm trying to get it to work with an array but my mesh is still warping when it wraps around the curve.